# Where is the name 'Stellar' derived from?

Tags: history

Where is the name 'Stellar' derived from?

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stellar_(payment_network)) doesn't mention it, and while the [stellar.org website](https://www.stellar.org/lumens/) mentions that it was the original name of the network's 'coin' (now called 'lumen', and I do get the reference from stars to [lumens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lumen_(unit))), it doesn't explain where the name Stellar itself comes from.

Answer (score 2):

I am not part of Stellar team, but was following Stellar since they forked from Ripple (and also Ripple until that point). My take on this is as follows:

Since the beginning, Stellar have a really [cute comic](https://www.stellar.org/stories/adventures-in-galactic-consensus-chapter-1) to explain how it's consensus protocol works. The main point was derived from problem of what kind of inter**stellar** blockchain is needed to work not only for us, but also for and together with aliens out there. That also implicitly crossed out proof-of-work consensus due 51% attack if aliens with supercomputers would come by.

Therefore Stellar (aka stars) is just a pun on it's strength that it can work out nicely in inter**stellar** conditions where you have lots of different aliens with varying computing power and interests. Kind of analogy to the so called "superpowers" down here on earth.